# Post object from backbone to REST

Tags: rest, backbone.js

I am trying to post data from front-end to RESTful. I'm a backbone beginner, so my problems are probably easy to solve. But have struggled with this all day - so now I'm asking for guidance.

I have a button that use to add data to REST. So in my view I use `object.save();` to save an object to model.

Here is my model:

```
define(["underscore" , "backbone"],function(_ , Backbone){
   var Test = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url:'http://mysite.com/Test/Test.svc/AddTest',
        idAttribute: 'ID'
   });
   return Test;
});
```

View :

```
 define(["jquery" ,
    "underscore" ,
    "backbone" ,
    'models/Test',
    'views/Test',
],function($ , _ , Backbone , Test, TestView){
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
    //....
    },
   events : {
       "click #byn" :  function(){
         //....
       },
       'click #test' : 'addTest'
   },
   addTest : function(){
        var object = new Test();
        object.set({
           "ID" : 0,
           "Name" : "",
           "CustomerID" : 106,
           "Type" : 0,
           "LastUpdated" : "\/Date(1383152400000+0700)\/",
           "Detail" : [
               {
                   "ID" : 0,
                   "TID" : 0,
                   "ItemID" : 22776,
                   "Quantity" : 2,
                   "LastUpdated" : "\/Date(1383152400000+0700)\/"
               }
           ]
       });
       object.save();
       var _wlView = new TestView({model:object});
   },
   render : function(){
        //....
   }
});
return HomeView;
});
```

To be truth, I really don't know how could I post the object that I have saved in my view `object.save();` to the restful throw the rest url like http://mysite.com/Test/Test.svc/AddTest.

Comment: For starters, you didn't define a url for the `Test` model. Secondly, is `object` an instance of `Backbone.Model`?

Comment: I have tried `var Test = Backbone.Model.extend({
url:'http://mysite.com/Test/Test.svc/AddTest',idAttribute: 'ID'
   });` But it didn't make any sense :/

Comment: Yes, sure. `object` is an instance of `TestModel`.

Comment: I suggest adding the relevant view code and where you are creating the model, so someone can see where your going wrong. Here's a simplistic `model.save()` demo. Open the console to see the request. http://jsfiddle.net/xKJ5S/

Comment: @fbynite : I added code in my question.

Comment: @fbynite : Any idea about that fbynite?

Answer (score 1):

Url of model should be declared as urlRoot value and it is better to have it relative (e.g. "/AddTest").

Then the backend route for save action will be "actual url" + "urlRoot".

Comment: Excuse me, the back end route, what did you mean here?

Comment: I meant server-side route accessible e.g. in PHP script.

Comment: Here, I use backbone then connect to REST. So where does the back-end route locate?

Comment: Sorry, but in my opinion REST means Representational state transfer. Which it is not something that actually create responses to your requests, but it only transfers request from client-side (front-end) to server-side (back-end). Anyway you need to declare URL of the model as I mentioned before. Then correct REST url will be "actual url" + "urlRoot".

Comment: Declared URL of model `url:'/AddTest', but correct REST url will be "actual url" + "urlRoot" << I really don't know, how to do it. http://mysite.com/Test/Test.svc/AddTest is the my web service URL, handle adding data that pass from client side(model). So how could I modify it?

Comment: No, don't modify it. Just set model's urlRoot to "mysite.com/Test/Test.svc/AddTest".

Comment: Setting up custom url property will make the custom urlRoot to be ignored due this property is used in the default url behavior. So I only use urlRoot. After using it, I got `307 Temporary Redirect
 ` in my console.